# Bootstrap 3 issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html is as

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" >
            <img class="img-responsive " src="images/image1.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly in *chrome* and *firefox*, both the div inside row class come side by side, i get text on left side and image on the right. But when tested on *Internet Explorer (ie8)* the div with class *col-lg-6* takes the entire width of the screen and so is the div with class *col-lg-4*.

The style **width:60%** or so in percentage seems not to be recognized by Internet Explorer. But I have not defined the container width anywhere explicitly. In **bootstrap.css** it takes up automatically for each size.

How can I get this working on *Internet Explorer* properly. thanks.

Comment: Have you used shim and response.js?

Comment: @Dznr yes, I have used html5shiv.js and respond.min.js

Comment: Have a look here http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/10/using-bootstrap-3-with-internet-explorer-8-ie8/

Comment: @Dznr tried it, but the issue remains the same

Comment: Did you have a look here: http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#browsers. Internet Explorer 8 and Respond.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already its too late to reply to this question. Now only i came with this issue. For me it solved. Try using:

add **.col-xs-12** to your responsive image.

Check the link
http://www.bootply.com/116378

Answer (score 3):

try use this in **head** section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```